# Are having TRIGGERs for every upvote/downvote detrimental in terms of performance?

Tags: mysql, trigger

I plan to have three tables: `Users`, `User_Reputation` and `Voting_Records`. The `Users` table would hold the primary key `id` for the registered users, along with personal information such as email and passwords. If they upvote something, it would record it in the `Voting_Records like so:`

```
+------+-------------+-----------+--------+
|  id  |   user_id   | author_id |  vote  |
+------+-------------+-----------+--------+
|  3   |   12389129  |  123421   |   -1   |
+------+-------------+-----------+--------+
```

With the `user_id` and `author_id` being a foreign key to the `id` of the Users table, this would subtract 1 from the overall reputation.

So instead of using `SUM()` for every time a user queries for a total of their reputation, would it be more beneficial to have `TRIGGER` to update the `total_votes` on the `User_Reputation` table every time someone upvotes/downvotes on their profile? It would definitely be more easy to implement features such as badges, which would be automatically awarded to people with more than X points.

Comment: You must ensure that there is no interference between concorrent updates.

Comment: @Akina Can you give me an example what an "interference" would be?

Comment: Can a user downvote an author multiple times?  If not, do you prevent this with `UNIQUE(user_id, author_id)`?  If so, get rid of `id` and make that pair the `PRIMARY KEY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called an aggregate table. This is a valid strategy.

You could also *defer* the calculation of user reputation if you are not bothered with real-time updates. Some sites do DB maintenance during the night, rebuild indexes etc. Since we are talking about user reputation, it's no big deal if the current stats are only reflected the day after. I don't think people will even notice.

`User_Reputation` could be a field in your table `Users`. It is simply an integer value that is incremented or decremented when an upvote or downvote is recorded. If you are writing more than one records, then wrap it up in a **transaction**:

1. Add a record in `Voting_Records`
2. Update table `users`: increment/decrement the value of `User_Reputation`

It doesn't have to be a trigger, it could be a standalone SQL statement or a block of code in a stored procedure, as long as there is a transaction to ensure consistency and as mentioned above, you have to consider concurrent updates.

You can even make the DB read-only for a short while when maintenance is in progress, I think that's what Stack Exchange does (sometimes).

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for a coherent answer!